# How can I establish the bluetooth connection with multiple activities?

Tags: java, android

[This is part of my  class BluetoothService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV1YR.png)

In this class I have some methods and another subclass to manage the threads for the connection process between the devices

[In this method I look for the device that is synchronized with the device and I made the connection. "'Devicelist" is an activity where I register the equipment that was linked to my device, through BroadcastReceiver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R45H4.png)

[This is my Handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBLDn.png)

[onActivityResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0vkk.png)

Comment: Sorry for the inconveniences I am new is my first post

Comment: And yes I read the service doc of google :(